# Make "indefinite-articles" a synonym for "indefinite-article"

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There were two questions tagged with [indefinite-articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-articles), and I changed the tag to [indefinite-article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-article).
Should we make [indefinite-articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-articles) a synonym of [indefinite-article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-article)?

Comment: Uh, I will leave the decision to our linguist mods. On the one hand, we [previously agreed](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/72/) to use plural in tags. On the other hand, there is but one indefinite article in English. (Yes, yes, there is *a* and there is *an*, but they are both forms of *an*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been done: the master is in the plural for [definite-articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-articles) and [indefinite-articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-articles).

Answer (score 2):

I support this suggestion. Yes, there is only one indefinite article in the dictionary, but there are certainly multiple *instances* of the indefinite article. The pluralization "indefinite articles" sounds preferable to me.

Comment: I am suggesting the other way around: keep _indefinite-article_ and make _indefinite-articles_ its synonym.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Feel free to post that as an opposing answer so people can vote?

Comment: @MrHen I have already created the question; if users agree with me, then they should vote the question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Voting the question up is agreeing that it is a good question. Voting an answer up is agreeing that it is a good answer. Putting an answer in your question is bad form.

Comment: @MRHen This is the meta site; if you down vote my "question" is because you don't agree with what I am proposing, not because you don't find the question useful. In fact, this is a request, and I have to report what my request is. The term "question" is not the most appropriate for a meta site; when it is a request, it is not a question at all.

Comment: @kiamlaluno. Meh. You used the term question; I used the term question. The decision of which tag should stick around is apparently contended so it sounds like a discussion is relevant. I think a synonym should exist but I am unable to say "this problem should be fixed" without saying "I agree with this implementation." Meta or not, this strikes me as bad form. (Not super-evil-form or oh-dear-what-have-you-done-form but merely not-optimally-efficient-form.)

Comment: @MrHen I used the term "question" because the user interface says "Ask question." `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Haha, fair enough. :)